# Calculate the difference between two dates in React Native

Tags: react-native

I need to calculate the difference between two dates in days

i bring today date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10) = 2019-04-17
and the other date in the same form

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```js
var msDiff = new Date("June 30, 2035").getTime() - new Date().getTime();    //Future date - current date
var daysTill30June2035 = Math.floor(msDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
console.log(daysTill30June2035);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement it yourself, but why would you? The solution to that already exists, and somebody else has taken care (and still is taking care) that it works as it should.

Use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org).

```
import differenceInDays from 'date-fns/difference_in_days';
```

If you really want to bash your head, you can get difference in milliseconds and then divide by number of milliseconds in a day. Sounds good to me, but I'm not 100% sure if it works properly.

```
const differenceInDays = (a, b) => Math.floor(
  (a.getTime() - b.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you manipulate many dates, maybe an external library like [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) could be useful. There are multiple add-ons like the [date range](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/) one.

Once installed, you need to create a range

```
const start = new Date(2011, 2, 5);
const end   = new Date(2011, 5, 5);
const range = moment.range(start, end);
```

Then could get the [difference](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range#difference) by doing something like

```
range.diff('months'); // 3
range.diff('days');   // 92
range.diff();         // 7945200000
```

Hope it could be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var d1 = new Date("2019/04/17") //firstDate
var d2 = new Date("2011/02/01") //SecondDate
var diff = Math.abs(d1-d2); //in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Use differenceInDays, parseISO from "date-fns"

---

```
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
import { differenceInDays, parseISO } from "date-fns";

 let day = differenceInDays(
        parseISO(your end date),
        parseISO(yout first Date)
      );
console.log("differenceInDays",differenceInDays)
```